# How to get id of model while doing store function in controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to insert into two tables that are related through a many to many relationship, but I need the user id to pass to the related table, how do I get it?

This are the `store` and `getCountry` function:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $users = $request->all();

    try
    {
        DB::beginTransaction();
        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            $dbUser = $this->getUser($user['USERNAME']);
            Log::error($dbUser);
            $dbUser->name = $user['NOMBRE'];
            $dbUser->user_name = $user['USERNAME'];
            $dbUser->email = $user['CORREO'];
            $dbUser->last_name = $user['APELLIDO'];
            $dbUser->password = $user['PASSWORD'];

            $this->isSet('TIPO-USUARIO', $user);
            $user_type_id = $this->getUserId($user['TIPO-USUARIO']);
            $dbUser->user_type_id = $user_type_id->id;

            foreach (explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $user['PAIS-USUARIO'])) as $c)
            {
                $country = $this->getCountry($c);
                $dbUser->countries()->save($country);
            }

            $dbUser->save();
        }

        DB::commit();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        DB::rollBack();
        throw new HttpException(500, 'My error message');
    }
}
```

```
private function getCountry($id)
{
    $country_id = Country::where('id', $id)->first();

    return $country_id;
}
```

The error i get right now is:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:
>
> 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `user_country` (`country_id`, `user_id`) values (1, ?))

Comment: $dbUser = $this->getUser($user['USERNAME']); 
Does the $dbUser have id value, what is the value of $dbUser->id;

Comment: You need to save the `$dbUser` first before trying to attach a country to it.

Comment: @Surace i'm getting the data from an excel file that doesn't have an id, but the table does have an id that auto increments

Comment: @user1669496 Thanks! solved my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that it can't attach a country to a user without the user first having been created (this is your foreign keys being put to work).

All you should need to do is save the user first so that Laravel knows the user id when it tries to attach that user to the country.

```
$dbUser->save();

foreach (explode(',', str_replace(' ', '', $user['PAIS-USUARIO'])) as $c) {
    $country = $this->getCountry($c);
    $dbUser->countries()->save($country);
}
```